# Deploy to localhost from Visual Studio

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, iis, binding, iis-express

I'm working on 'asp.mvc' web site. When i deploy it to 'iis express', site is available from 'localhost:333'.
[image]
 I want to deploy this site to 'iis' (and keep url like localhost:xxx), but when i change 'iis express' to 'iis', i receive an error.
[image]

How to deploy site to iis 10 from VisualStudio 2013/2015 and access it from localhost:xxx?

Comment: Behind he scene such editing of IIS configuration requires you to run VS as administrator.

Answer (score 0):

By default IIS, is configured for port 80. Hence by default, in IIS it can be configured as `http://localhost/webapplicationname`
But it can override in IIS by either editing the existing binding for specific port or create an new website with the port 444 and configure the web deploy accordingly.